# How to validate both email using bootstrapValidator (identical)

Tags: bootstrapvalidator

I am using bootstrapValidator (identical) to check both email are same or not , its working fine but I want error messages in the same line, now they are in two lines. See here https://screenshots.firefox.com/abfJ97LEjpAncVoW/localhost . I tried many way and found in google but did not get any solution. Following is my validation code:

```
$('#formid').bootstrapValidator({

        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-alert',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            firstmail: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The email address is required and can\'t be empty'
                    },
                     emailAddress: {
                        message: 'The input is not a valid email address'
                    },
                    identical: {
                        field: '2ndmail',
                        message: 'The email and its confirm are not the same'
                    }
                }
            },
            2ndmail: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The email address is required and can\'t be empty'
                    },
                     emailAddress: {
                        message: 'The input is not a valid email address'
                    },
                    identical: {
                        field: 'firstmail',
                        message: 'The email and its confirm are not the same'
                    }
                }
            },
            },

    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code solved my problem , I have added it below this  $('#formId').bootstrapValidator({.....});

```
$('#formid').bootstrapValidator({

feedbackIcons: {
    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-alert',
    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
},
fields: {
    firstmail: {
        validators: {
            notEmpty: {
                message: 'The email address is required and can\'t be empty'
            },
             emailAddress: {
                message: 'The input is not a valid email address'
            },
            identical: {
                field: '2ndmail',
                message: 'The email and its confirm are not the same'
            }
        }
    },
    2ndmail: {
        validators: {
            notEmpty: {
                message: 'The email address is required and can\'t be empty'
            },
             emailAddress: {
                message: 'The input is not a valid email address'
            },
            identical: {
                field: 'firstmail',
                message: 'The email and its confirm are not the same'
            }
        }
    },
    },

})

.on('error.validator.bv', function(e, data) {
// $(e.target)    --> The field element
// data.bv        --> The BootstrapValidator instance
// data.field     --> The field name
// data.element   --> The field element
// data.validator --> The current validator name

data.element
    .data('bv.messages')
    // Hide all the messages
    .find('.help-block[data-bv-for="' + data.field + '"]').hide()
    // Show only message associated with current validator
    .filter('[data-bv-validator="' + data.validator + '"]').show();
});
```